# _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'x'

Tags: python, pickle

I have [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpboixa1xgojzy7/bof.pkl?dl=1) pickle file, which I'm trying to unpickle using the following Python script:

```
import _pickle as pickle

pickle_file = open('bof.pkl', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unpickle.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = pickle.load(pickle_file)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'x'.
```

How can I solve this issue, as I couldn't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 12):

I found that the program was using `from sklearn.externals import joblib`, and thus saved the pickle file as follows:

```
joblib.dump(....)
```

I was thus able to load the pickle content as follows:

```
clf = joblib.load('pickle_file.pkl')
```

Comment: oooooo here's a fun nasty error:
`
ValueError: You may be trying to read with python 3 a joblib pickle generated with python 2. This feature is not supported by joblib.`